# Handler sendMessageDelayed works only the first time

Tags: android, handler

I am having problems with a Handler. It works fine the first time I instantiate it only.

The handler is inside a View:

```
    private long delayMillis; 
    private long mMoveDelay = 1000;

    /**
     * Create a simple handler that we can use to cause animation to happen.  We
     * set ourselves as a target and we can use the sleep()
     * function to cause an update/invalidate to occur at a later date.
     */
    private RefreshHandler mRedrawHandler;


    class RefreshHandler extends Handler {

        // serve per far vedere tile 2 almeno un tempo prestabilito checkTime

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {


            delayMillis+=mMoveDelay;
            System.out.println("--->handleMessage mMoveDelay"+10000);
            System.out.println("--->handleMessage delayMillis"+delayMillis);


            sleep();
        }

        public void sleep() {

            //this.removeMessages(0);
            sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(0), mMoveDelay);
            System.out.println("--->sleep delayMillis"+delayMillis);
        }
    };
```

After a few times I run

```
    mRedrawHandler = new RefreshHandler();
    mRedrawHandler.sleep();
```

sendMessageDelayed is called instantaneously. The problem seems similar in this post:

[Handler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, delay) not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076139/handler-sendmessagedelayedmsg-delay-not-working-correctly)

Have you got any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: I solved executing new RefreshHandler() one time only.

Answer (score 0):

In the sleep method what's the object of obtainMessage(0)?
It seems to be the problem. You cannot use a message object which used last time. you've got to create new message object.